# Is it possible to calculate a conditional cumsum with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to calculate the historical number of hits a player has gotten in day vs night games. For example given a player with 5 games, sorted from oldest games to most recent game the dn_hits column (daynight) for the first row would be zeros because this is the first game. The dn_hits for the second row would look at if the second game was a day game or a night game and then perform a backward-looking cumsum() on the hits column - summing all hits that happened on a day or night as the case may be. This would happen for each row in the group.

I have a sample data frame and sample output below. I've also included some psuedo code of what I believe I need to do to make the calculation

You can see in the output below:

**Row 1**: the dn_hits column for the first row for player AJ is 0 (no prior games or hits to cumsum);

**Row 2**: the second row  for player AJ is 2 (AJ's second game was a day game and so was his first game. Therefore, we conditionally cumsum the first game hits = 2 where dn = "day");

**Row 3**: the third row for player AJ is 0 (game three is a night game, prior to game 3 player AJ only played in (2) day games so the conditional cumsum of hits from where dn = "night" is 0)

Can this be accomplished with dplyr or is this a job for purrr.

```
 library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(game=c(seq(1:5),seq(1,5)),name=c("AJ","AJ","AJ","AJ","AJ","CJ","CJ","CJ","CJ","CJ"),
hits = c(2,1,0,1,3,2,1,4,1,0), dn=c("Day","Day","Night","Night","Night","Night","Day","Night","Night","Day"))


output  <- tibble(game=c(seq(1:5),seq(1,5)),name=c("AJ","AJ","AJ","AJ","AJ","CJ","CJ","CJ","CJ","CJ"),
hits = c(2,1,0,1,3,2,1,4,1,0), dn=c("Day","Day","Night","Night","Night","Night","Day","Night","Night","Day"), dn_hits=c(0,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,6,1)) 

# Original tibble

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>     game name   hits dn   
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     1 AJ        2 Day  
#>  2     2 AJ        1 Day  
#>  3     3 AJ        0 Night
#>  4     4 AJ        1 Night
#>  5     5 AJ        3 Night
#>  6     1 CJ        2 Night
#>  7     2 CJ        1 Day  
#>  8     3 CJ        4 Night
#>  9     4 CJ        1 Night
#> 10     5 CJ        0 Day

# Desired Output

output
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>     game name   hits dn    dn_hits
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1     1 AJ        2 Day         0
#>  2     2 AJ        1 Day         2
#>  3     3 AJ        0 Night       0
#>  4     4 AJ        1 Night       0
#>  5     5 AJ        3 Night       1
#>  6     1 CJ        2 Night       0
#>  7     2 CJ        1 Day         0
#>  8     3 CJ        4 Night       2
#>  9     4 CJ        1 Night       6
#> 10     5 CJ        0 Day         1


# This is what I think needs to happen but not sure how to implement it. 

#df %>% 
#group_by(name) %>%
#arrange(name, desc(game)) %>% 
#mutate(dn_hits = cumsum(dn = [dn on current row],hits, 0))
```

EDIT: I also tried the following:

```
df %>% 
group_by(name) %>%
arrange(name, desc(game)) %>% 
mutate(dn_hits = map_int(dn, ~ cumsum(if_else(.x == dn, hits, 0))))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `dn_hits`. x `false` must be a double vector, not an integer vector. i Input `dn_hits` is `map_int(dn, ~cumsum(if_else(.x == dn, hits, 0L)))`. i The error occurred in group 1: name = "AJ".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `group_by` by `dn` to make a 'conditional' cumulative sum:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name, dn) %>% 
  mutate(dn_hits = cumsum(hits)-hits)
```